# How to serve XHTML 5 from Play 2?

Tags: playframework-2.0, html

Is there anything special I have to do? Adding the xmlns attribute to the template is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Scala, in the controller(s), add:

```
import play.api.http.ContentTypeOf
import play.api.templates.Html

implicit val xhtml = ContentTypeOf[Html](Some("application/xhtml+xml"))
```

In the templates, ensure that you have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and that your HTML (including any generated HTML passed to the template) is well-formed XML.